# Figuring if a link is clicked on a webView - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, webview

I am using a custom webview to show a tabbar when user touches on the webview. But when I clicked on a link in a webview, tabbar is shown for a little time and then page loads. I am using this custom webview to detect touch: http://github.com/psychs/iphone-samples/blob/b772b963f2acf18d478b41b44555992fcd8d4f31/WebViewTappingHack/Classes/PSWebView.m

Can I detect if a link clicked or not? Because a link stands on the webview, webview detects the touch and also it loads the page... I want to prevent it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did a workaround and solved by myself...

My links are at the top & bottom of the page so I got screen coordinates by the following code and if pos.y < some value and pos.y > some value then do not show the menu...

```
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView: [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
NSLog(@"Position of touch: %.3f, %.3f", pos.x, pos.y);
```

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 3):

**Using Javascript**

Instead of preventing the loading of the page, I would inject Javascript into the webview so that touching the link doesn't do anything.

I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219802/disabling-visible-links-in-uiwebview/2219816#2219816) a question similar to this not too long ago. Instead of disabling all links (like the other question) just look for the specific link you'd like to disable and **remove its `href` attribute**.

**Using a UIWebview Delegate**

Alternatively, if you want to be able to respond to a user attempting to click the link (perhaps to give them a message), you can set the UIWebview's delegate and implement the [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) method and return `NO` if the URL attempting to be loaded is the one you'd like to block.

As an aside, it's usually best practice to maintain a whitelist as opposed to a blacklist for this sort of exclusion. Rather than blocking links you don't want it might be better to block all links, *except* for the ones you know are safe to navigate to.

Comment: Actually I want to prevent to show tabbar, not loading page... When user touches on the webview and if it is link which touched on, then I do not want to show the tabbar, but if it is NOT link I want to show tabbar... Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 3):

UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked = Tells you when a link has clicked.
Only check you call

self.webView.delegate = self;

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```